# Why socket closing itself after sending data once?

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

I have a client-server app.
It opens a socket on client side, then I input data to send, it's also sent to other clients, but then the socket is closed. Why? I have tried many different approaches, like shifting `din` and `dout` to thread itself, adding some handlers, etc. But no progress yet.

I saw some other problems like this, but the solutions there are not applicable to my problem (I am not so experienced in sockets). Would like a solution to my specific problem.

Errors:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:927)
    at com.uniqueapps.network.ClientThread.lambda$run$1(ClientThread.java:23)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:998)
    at com.uniqueapps.network.ClientThread.lambda$run$0(ClientThread.java:28)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at com.uniqueapps.network.ClientThread.lambda$run$0(ClientThread.java:27)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Server.java codes:

```
package com.uniqueapps.network;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    final static int PORT = 5555;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static ArrayList<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        ClientThread client = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
                        client.run();
                        clients.add(client);
                        System.out.println("New client joined: " + client.socket.getLocalPort());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ClientThread.java codes:

```
package com.uniqueapps.network;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            boolean run = true;
            while (run) {
                try (DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                    String text = din.readUTF();
                    if (!text.equals("")) {
                        new Thread(() -> {
                            for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clients) {
                                try (DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientThread.socket.getOutputStream())) {
                                    dout.writeUTF(text);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                } catch (EOFException ignored) {
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Server.clients.remove(this);
                    run = false;
                    System.out.println("Client left: " + socket.getLocalPort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Client.java codes:

```
package com.uniqueapps.network;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);

            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
                    while (true) {
                        String text = scn.nextLine();
                        if (!text.equals("")) {
                            try {
                                dout.writeUTF(text);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            String text = din.readUTF();
                            if (!text.equals("")) {
                                System.out.println(text);
                            }
                        } catch (EOFException ignored) {
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit:

Thanks to Michael Lee, i understood the problem i have been trying to understand for weeks. I remade the code, but i am stuck a place.

I got to know that the `.run();` method of "runnable" halts the current thread, but `.start();` of "thread" doesn't. So i removed threads from all places, except one. This place is still getting the "Socket closed" error (If i keep runnable here, then the thread is halted, and the message not relayed to other clients). How can i overcome this?

Server.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    final static int PORT = 8686;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static ArrayList<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server ready! Running on port " + PORT);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("New client joined: " + clientSocket.getPort());
                    ClientThread client = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
                    System.out.println("Created thread for client.");
                    clients.add(client);
                    System.out.println("Added client to list.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ClientThread.java:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.start();
        System.out.println("Started thread for client.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean run = true;
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (run) {
                try {
                    String text = din.readUTF();
                    if (!text.equals("")) {
                        for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clients) {
                            try (DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientThread.socket.getOutputStream())) {
                                dout.writeUTF(text);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (EOFException ignored) {
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Server.clients.remove(this);
                    run = false;
                    System.out.println("Client left: " + socket.getPort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class ClientThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.start();
        System.out.println("Started thread for client.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean run = true;
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (run) {
                try {
                    String text = din.readUTF();
                    if (!text.equals("")) {
                        for (ClientThread clientThread : Server.clients) {
                            try (DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientThread.socket.getOutputStream())) {
                                dout.writeUTF(text);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (EOFException ignored) {
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Server.clients.remove(this);
                    run = false;
                    System.out.println("Client left: " + socket.getPort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [I think the port 5555 is not for personal use.](http://tcp-udp-ports.com/port-5555.htm), try something else, like 8686.

Comment: Changed the port, still same error @Xarencia

Comment: Because you use separate threads the read and write, and you close the input/output stream in either thread when you're done, it is not deterministic when the socket closes. Closing the input stream or output stream from a socket will close the entire socket, including the output stream or input stream you didn't explicitly close.

Answer (score 0):

In your *ClientThread*, after `din.readUTF(); if (!text.equals("")) { ...`, you should **directly** start processing the incoming data in current thread, rather than initializing a new thread to handle them.

Because in you current thread, the one holding the connected socket, probably **closed before** the new thread has not even started up. As [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) says:

> void close() throws Exception
>
> Closes this resource, relinquishing any underlying resources. This method is **invoked automatically** on objects managed by the **try-with-resources statement**.

That is why you got `Socket Closed` exceptions.

One more thing is that, there are too many threads in either `Server` or `Client`. Most of time such things are unnecessary, say, for a rather simple application. Because they are not quite managed well in your codes, which more likely makes your program behave unexpectedly in the future. Try use threads **only if necessary**, instead of using them *as much as possible*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. I have been thinking for it for weeks. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Please check out